# How to force `async_std` task to run on a single thread in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and trying async for the first time in rust. Here in the example I''m running a cpu intensive op of recursive fibonacci series using `async-std` and whether I run a single task or two tasks it is taking roughly the same time (~7secs).

It looks like the tasks are being executed on multiple threads by the async runtime.

Is there any way to force the async tasks to run on the same thread?

```rust
use std::time;
use async_std::task;

fn main() {

    let start = time::Instant::now();

    let s1 = task::spawn(fib_async(46));
    let s2 = task::spawn(fib_async(46));

    task::block_on(s1);
    task::block_on(s2);
    let elap = time::Instant::now().duration_since(start);

    println!("time took for tasks to finish: {} seconds", elap.as_secs());

}


async fn fib_async(n: i32) -> i32 {
    fib(n)
}

fn fib(n: i32) -> i32 {
    if n == 0 || n == 1 {
        1
    } else {
        fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs of [`async_std::task`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.5.0/async_std/task/index.html) you cannot.

> This module is similar to std::thread, except it uses asynchronous tasks in place of threads.

So it is intended to start a new thread, like you start a new thread with `std::thread::spawn`.

If you want to process data sequentially, you could implement a worker producer pattern:

```rust
use async_std::task;
use std::time;

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = flume::unbounded();

    let s = task::spawn(async move {
        for n in rx.into_iter() {
            println!("Calc fib of {}", n);
            let fib = fib_async(n).await;
            println!("{}", fib);
        }
    });

    let start = time::Instant::now();


    tx.send(40).unwrap();
    tx.send(40).unwrap();

    drop(tx);
    s.await;

    let elap = time::Instant::now().duration_since(start);
    println!("time took for tasks to finish: {} seconds", elap.as_secs());
}

async fn fib_async(n: i32) -> i32 {
    fib(n)
}

fn fib(n: i32) -> i32 {
    if n == 0 || n == 1 {
        1
    } else {
        fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    }
}
```

With Cargo dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
async-std = { version = "1.5", features = ["attributes"] }
flume = "0.7"
```